# How to add dynamic div , react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I try to create multiple dives from an object that contains 9 arrays, each array contains different coordinates, and my goal is to create a div for each array and display them on the screen according to their coordinates.

This is what I did :

```
class Boxes extends Component {

  createBox = (box) => {
    if(box !== undefined) {
      console.log('box :', box);
      return <div className='bounding-box'> <h1>Test</h1></div>
    }
  }

  createBoxes = (boxes) => {
    for (let index = 0; index < boxes.length; index++) {
      let box = {
        x1: boxes[index].x1,
        y1: boxes[index].y1,
        x2: boxes[index].x2,
        y2:boxes[index].y2
      }
      this.createBox(box);   
    }      
  }

  render() { 
    return (     
      <div>
          {this.createBox(this.createBoxes(this.props.box))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Boxes;
```

The variable `this.props.box` contains the object with the arrays

What I did was go through the object, and send each array to a function that would create a div for it
But it does not make me any div.

I'll be happy to understand where my mistake is, what am I not doing right?

Thank you

Comment: Probably give your `div` a `className` and not an `id`

Comment: Also you're not returning anything from your `createBoxes` function

Comment: i return from this function one div : <div className='bounding-box'> <h1>Test</h1></div> but when i run  it, i dont see this div

Comment: @AmosGuetta issues with your code are not returning anything from createBoxes and also returning nothing in case of box being undefined. In that case, return a null so that react doesn't render that :). Check my answer for a working example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createBoxes` function does not return anything, so passing it as parameter to `createBox` function does not work.
Also you should assign a **unique id** to each div element, so I added an index parameter to `createBox` function.

And I changed the name of props.box to props.boxes, which is more accurate.

Consider using something like following code:

```js
class Boxes extends Component {

createBox = (box, index) => {
if(box !== undefined) {
    console.log('box :', box);
    return  <div id={"bounding-box-" + index}>box ${index}</div>
  }
}

createBoxes = (boxes) =>{

return boxes.map((box, index) => {
  let box = {
        x1: boxes[index].x1,
        y1: boxes[index].y1,
        x2: boxes[index].x2,
        y2:boxes[index].y2
    }
    return this.createBox(box, index);
})

}

render() { 
    return (
        <div>
            {this.createBoxes(this.props.boxes)}
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi, thank you.  but this code does not working, it just create the first div (id=bounding-box-0). and that all.

Comment: My bad, there was an extra return phrase. I edited the code, working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-f1vbh8)

Comment: You're welcome :) could you please upvote the accepted answer?

Comment: No upvote,not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a solution for the same. Hope this helps. Check this [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/7zyvlyk60j)

Comment: @AmosGuetta please upvote the answer so that anyone with same problem can find it quick in future